# How to Fetch upstream with conflicts?

Tags: git, visual-studio, github, git-pull, visual-studio-2022

I am trying to contribute to a public project (main project) on GitHub. Here is what I did

1. Forked the main project.
2. Created a branch from my fork (branch name `fix-user-form`).
3. Using VisualStudio 2022, I cloned the `fix-user-form` branch, made my code changes and committed the changes.
4. Created a pull request into the main project.

Now, I am trying to fetch the upstream to pull all current changes from the main project. So I did the following

1. Using GitHub in my main branch I clicked Fetch up stream and it worked with no issue.
2. Using GitHub Switched to my `fix-user-form` and clicked on Fetch up stream. but I get the

[image]

I created a pull request as per the instruction, but now I am a bit lost on how to find the conflicts in order to resolve the conflicts.

I am using VisualStudio 2022. Can this be done in VisualStudio or does it have to be online?

Answer (score 0):

As explained in [Sync your fork to latest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/forks?view=azure-devops&tabs=visual-studio#sync-your-fork-to-latest=), you should

- add the upstreeam repository (the one you have forked)
  [image: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/media/forks/vs-te-upstream-added.png?view=azure-devops]
- fetch it
  [image: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/media/forks/vs-te-sync.png?view=azure-devops]
- rebase your PR branch on top of upstream/main (assuming it is the target branch of your PR): resolve conflicts then.
  [image: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/media/forks/vs-te-rebase.png?view=azure-devops]
  (The picture shows `upstream/master`, but replace `master` with the name of the target branch in your case)
- force push

That will update the online PR, which will no longer have conflicts.